# How app can find colored characters

Tags: python

I wrote some code that gives 10 character lenght random character password, and ive randomly colored characters. I've put one color that i need to be in output colors. And now question: how application can find all (yellow in this case) characters? User can see them but how app can find them? I am using Python 3.4

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters, digits

chars = ascii_letters + digits

word = "".join([choice(chars) for i in range(10)])

R = '\033[31m'  # red
G = '\033[32m'  # green
B = '\033[34m'  # blue
P = '\033[35m'  # purple
Y = '\033[93m'  # yellow

colors = [R, G, B, P, Y]

colorpass = "\033[93m"
for char in word:
    colorpass += char + choice(colors)

print(colorpass)
```

Comment: Pre printing: Modify your loop to indicate that the next colour is going to be yellow. Post print: Search for all locations with `Y` and the position next to it will be a yellow character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need this isolated - its just a "find all substrings" problem.

i.e.

```
import re
for i in re.finditer(re.escape(Y), colorpass):
    print colorpass[i.end()]
```

You need to escape special characters in your substring to make valid regex matcher. `re.escape` is great way to do this dynamically.

Comment: I have worked with your answer and it works, but sometimes it gives error. Ive added this to my code:

w = "".join((colorpass[i.end()]) for i in re.finditer(re.escape(Y), colorpass))
print(w)

And error is: IndexError: string index out of range. How can i avoid it?

Comment: I've figured out why my error appears. Now need to stop it. Thank You for help

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this from the top of my head is during the loop, append the colours to a list. Then, later when you need to "detect" the colours you can call the list and item 1 of the list can correspond to letter 1 of the coloured string.

```
colourList = []
for char in word:
    colorpass += char + choice(colors)
    colourList.append(some_sort_of_color_identification)

print(colorpass)

...
```

Retrieving colors:

```
for char in range(0, len(word)):
    detectedColor = colourList[char]
    print(detectedColor)
```